# Can everything be accelerating away with a nearly constant Hubble Parameter?

Tags: cosmology, acceleration, space-expansion

Simple Physics shows everything accelerating away over time with a  nearly constant Hubble parameter.
The velocity of recession is $V=DH_o$: The change in distance over time is $∆D=V∆T=DH_o∆T$: The change in velocity for that distance $∆V=∆DH_o$: Substituting and reducing above   $∆V=DH_0^2∆T$: The resulting recession acceleration $A=∆V/∆T=DH_0^2.$
Where D,V,A,T are distance,velocity and acceleration and time respectively and $H_0$ is the Hubble parameter.
Let me turn this into an observation plus math.  We have observed the Hubble parameter over time and the changes are small, maybe 10%.  If I take the observed  parameter times the distance to an object times a small time interval and sum them over time.  For a billion years ago to present we find all objects have moved about 7.7% further away and receding 7.7% faster for a 7.7% momentum gain and a 16% gain in kinetic energy.  For two billion years ago to present we find all objects have moved about 16% further away and receding 16% faster for a 16% momentum gain and a 35% gain in kinetic energy.  Does this gain in momentum fit the current theories since the Hubble parameter has not significantly changed.

Comment: I am trying to understand why momentum (mass times Velocity) is used to explain the expansion of space.  I am also trying to avoid the complexities of a changing Hubble parameter(Dark matter and the Cosmological Constant),.  So in today's Universe if I observe an object for a long enough period of time, that object and every distant object will appear to accelerate (with respect to my reference frame) thus increasing its momentum.  I see this as a result  of our current observations.  Precision and time limit todays observation of acceleration.

Answer (score 3):

One point where you are wrong (or at least making an approximation that isn't yet true in our universe) is that the Hubble "constant" is not constant. Better to call it the Hubble parameter when discussing the evolution of the universe, such that
$$ \dot{a} = H(t) a(t),$$
where $a$ is the scale factor (distance between two galaxies) and $\dot{a}$ is it's rate of change (your velocity).

The solution to the Friedmann equation in a flat universe is
$$H^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho + \frac{\Lambda}{3},$$
where $\rho$ is the matter density (including dark matter) and $\Lambda$ is the cosmological constant.

As the universe expands, $\rho$ of course decreases, but $\Lambda$ remains constant.

Thus the Hubble "constant" actually decreases from its current value $H_0$ and asymptotically tends towards $ H = \sqrt{\Lambda/3}$ as time tends towards infinity. For the currently known cosmological parameters, $H$ will tend towards about $2 H_0/3$. If there were no $\Lambda$ then it would tend towards zero.

However, in a universe dominated by a cosmological constant (such as in the far future, or possibly during the inflationary epoch), then the Hubble parameter *is* a constant. This can be termed a [de Sitter universe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_universe).
In such a universe, the expansion is exponential
$$ a(t) =  \exp(Ht)$$
$$ \dot{a} = H\exp(Ht) = Ha$$
$$\ddot{a} = H^2 a$$
as per the derivation in your question.